# Dynamically create variable names?

Tags: python, variables

I have some logic which I need to repeat 6 times. Result is stored in variable at the end, but I need variable name to be something as `data1`, `data2`, `data3`, etc. So if I have:

```
for x in range(0, 3):
   ...some logic...
   data = result
```

How can I get data variable named as `data1`, `data2` etc based on the loop number?

Comment: use a dictionary instead

Comment: `data = [fn(x) for x in range(3)]`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can use dictionary like this: examples

```
>>> a = ['hello', 'banana', 'apple']
>>> my_dict = {}
>>> for x in range(len(a)):
...     my_dict[x] = a[x]
... 
>>> my_dict
{0: 'hello', 1: 'banana', 2: 'apple'}

>>> my_dict[1]
'banana'
```